# How to create own php templating system?

Tags: php, eval, templating

I have two files name `test.txt` that will contains the template code.I need to evalute this template to be evaluated by php.
`EVAL()` Function was giving some errors on ifelse and other similar conditions.

test.txt

```
@$firmware_path=true;
@$DIALPLAN=1312321;
@$MAX_LINES=3;
@$data=array();
@$OPERATOR_IP='';
@$enabled=true;
@ if ($firmware_path) 
@{
    firmware server: http://{$OPERATOR_IP}{$firmware_path}
@ }



@ for ($i = 1; $i <= $MAX_LINES; $i++)
@ {
    @ $enabled = isset($LINES[$i - 1]);
    @ if ($enabled) 
    @{
        @ $data = $LINES[$i -1];

        @ if ($data['USER_FULLNAME']) 
        @{
            @ if ($PHONE_LABEL) 
            @{
                @ $screenName = $data['USER_FULLNAME'] . ' ' . $data['TELNUM'];
                @ $screenName2 = $PHONE_LABEL;
            @ } 
            @else 
            @{
                @ $screenName = $data['USER_FULLNAME'];
                @ $screenName2 = $data['TELNUM'];
            @ }
        @ } 
        @else 
        @{
            @ $screenName = $data['TELNUM'];
            @ $screenName2 = $PHONE_LABEL;
        @ }

    @ }
@ }
```

index.php

```
<?php

$file = fopen("test.txt","r");
$arr=array();
while(! feof($file))
{
  $arr[]=fgets($file);
}


$format='';
foreach($arr as $key=>$value)
{
  if(substr(ltrim($value), 0, 1) === '@')
  {
    $result=str_replace('@','',$value);

    $format.=$result.PHP_EOL;

  }
  else
  {

    $format.='$final="'.$value.'";';
  }

}


 $format.=' return $final;';
echo eval($format);


?>
```

the result should be generated according to php

Comment: in my index.php file first i remove the @ sign

Comment: Your PHP code in the text doesn't seem to be correct. Have you ran it through an interpreter?

Comment: So, what does `$format` look like before you try to evaluate it?

Comment: guessing -  laravel blade? I cannot find another PHP template language that uses '@' in this way? suggestions...

Comment: maybe useful? [A standalone version of Laravel's Blade templating engine for use outside of Laravel.](https://github.com/jenssegers/blade)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved a problem like this . Its like php templating , in which we try to use custom changeable code to be executed in some scenarios.

Here is the algorithm i used for this :

> NOTE put the template code in `$arr`

```
$arr=str_replace('transliterate','urldecode',$arr);

$format='$final="";';
foreach($arr as $key=>$value)
{
if(substr(ltrim($value), 0, 1) === '@')
{
//run it as php line through eval
$result=str_replace('@','',$value);

$format.=$result.PHP_EOL;

}
else
{
 // just echo as normal php echo line
 $value=str_replace('"','\"',$value);

 $value=str_replace('{','".(',$value);
 $value=str_replace('}',')."',$value);

 $format.='$final.="'.$value.'";'.PHP_EOL;
}

}

 $format.=' return $final;';

$evaled_result= eval($format);
```